# JavaScript, MutationObserver misses mutations

Tags: javascript, dom, tampermonkey, userscripts, mutation-observers

I'm trying to create a user script for the Chess.com website. I need to detect changes in the class attribute on certain elements on the page.

There is a small problem: certain mutations of the class attribute are missed by the observer.

My question in short: **does anyone have any idea, from the general, conceptual point of the `MutationObserver` (at least), what might be the reason of this?**

---

A more detailed question:

I'll post the script below, in case anyone wants to try, but the behavior is this:

- I attached an observer to a black knight (I play for black), whichever appears first in the DOM, when I `pointerdown` on it, it is added a 'dragging' class. One change is observed, which is OK.

[image: chess-board]

- Then I release the pointer, no changes seem to occur to the class attribute, no observer call.
- Then I `pointerdown` again on the knight tile, to remove 'selection' fro it (not to make a move) and this is what I see (this step is marked with red):

[image: mutations-log]

An array of 3 MutationRecords is passed to the observer callback:

- in the first record we see the the old value is the same as the current value from step 1 (not marked with red) (which is normal and expected);
- in the second record (change 2) we see that the old value was `piece bn dragging` while the current value from the previous record (change 1 in the marked block) was `piece bn square-28`. **This means that somewhere in between the 'square-28' class had been removed and the 'dragging' one added and no mutation record for this has been reported.** The same problem is with step 3.

Some additional thoughts:

- I tried to reproduce such a situation on another dummy page, but I failed, the changes are always reported (even if they don't occur actually, like when removing a class which wasn't present `elem.classList.remove('unexisting-class')`).
- Firefox and Chrome both have the same behavior, so it looks like not a bug
- It can't be a call to `observer.takeRecords()` elsewhere, since in that case the queue would be completely empty, and change 1 wouldn't be present. So apparently the queue of changes is not empty, yet some changes, which must be there, are abscent.
- It can't be an overridden `MutationObserver`, since one seem to contain [native Code], no definition of it was present in the scripts.

The script is:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         so-question-chess.com
// @version      0.0.0-0
// @include      https://www.chess.com/play/*
// @run-at       document-end
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
  'use strict';
  const chessBoard = document.querySelector('chess-board');
  const observerBoard = new MutationObserver((changes) => {
    // attach the observer to the first black knight, when one appears
    for (const change of changes) {
      if (change.type === 'childList') {
        const addedNode = change.addedNodes.item(0);
        if (!addedNode) {
          continue;
        }
        const classList = addedNode.classList;
        //detect a black knight
        if (classList && classList.contains('bn') && classList.contains('piece')) {

          //The relevant part, the observer which observes changes on the class
          //attribute on the black knight piece
          const observerPiece = new MutationObserver((changes) => {
            console.group('single change array');
            for (const change of changes) {
              console.group('single change item');
              console.count('change');
              console.log('current value: ' + change.target.attributes.class.value);
              console.log('old value: ' + change.oldValue);
              console.groupEnd();
            }
            console.countReset('change');
            console.groupEnd();
          });
          observerPiece.observe(addedNode, {
            attributeFilter: ['class'],
            attributeOldValue: true,
            subtree: false,
          });
          //End of the relevant part


          observedBoard.disconnect();
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  });
  observerBoard.observe(chessBoard, {subtree: false, childList: true});

})();
```

I have no idea of why this is happening, and would be very grateful, if someone pointed to the reason of this.

Comment: The usual reason is that a parent/ancestor of that element was replaced.

Comment: @wOxxOm I don't see how this may be related. The parentElement is updated automatically and even if the observed element is taken out of its parent to another one it still has its attribute class, it (the element) is still observed (there is no mention in the docs that if the element is taken out it stops being observed).

Comment: @wOxxOm currently I'm suspecting it has something to do with an overridden console.log et al. They may report wrong values, cached or something

Comment: I see you disconnect the outer observer so my guess might still be applicable if the node gets swapped with a new one during that interval.

Comment: As for console.log, you can get the native value (just an example): document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('iframe')).contentWindow.console.log('foo')